# What is the difference between <NA> and NA?

Tags: r, na, missing-data

I have a factor named SMOKE with levels "Y" and "N". Missing values were replaced with NA (from the initial level "NULL"). However when I view the factor I get something like this:

```
head(SMOKE)
# N N <NA> Y Y N
# Levels: Y N
```

Why is R displaying `NA` as `<NA>`? And is there a difference?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

When you are dealing with `factors`, when the `NA` is wrapped in angled brackets ( `<NA>` ), that indicates that it is in fact NA.

When it is `NA` without brackets, then it is *not* NA, but rather a proper factor whose label is `"NA"`

```
# Note a 'real' NA and a string with the word "NA"
x <- factor(c("hello", NA, "world", "NA"))

x
[1] hello <NA>  world NA   
Levels: hello NA world      <~~ The string appears as a level, the actual NA does not. 

as.numeric(x)              
[1]  1 NA  3  2            <~~ The string has a numeric value (here, 2, alphabetically)
                               The NA's numeric value is just NA
```

---

#### Edit to answer @Arun's question:

`R` is simply trying to distinguish between a string whose value are the two letters `"NA"` and an actual missing value, `NA`
Thus the difference you see when displaying `df` versus `df$y`.  Example:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:4, y=c("a", NA_character_, "c", "NA"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Note the two different styles of NA:

```
> df
  x    y
1 1    a
2 2 <NA>
3 3    c
4 4   NA
```

However, if we look at just 'df$y'

```
[1] "a"  NA   "c"  "NA"
```

But, if we remove the quotation marks (similar to what we see when printing a data.frame to the console):

```
print(df$y, quote=FALSE)
[1] a    <NA> c    NA
```

And thus, we once again have the distinction of `NA` via the angled brackets.

Comment: RicardoSaporta, It's a bit unclear to me. While checking [**this answer from @SimonO101**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16315617/559784) I find that if you've a data.frame, ex: `df <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=c("a", "b", NA_character_, "d"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`, it still stays `<NA>`. Of course the question is for vectors. But still, this is not clear to me. Ex: When you print the column, `df$y` it disappears. But when you print `df`, it shows the angle brackets.

Comment: See also `addNA()`, e.g. `levels(addNA(x))`

Comment: Also probably worth showing this: `factor(c("NA", "<NA>", NA))`. Looking at the printed representation of something is not a great way to understand what it is!

Answer (score 13):

It is just the way that R displays `NA` in a factor:

```
> as.factor(NA)
[1] <NA>
Levels: 
> 
> f <- factor(c(1:3, NA))
> levels(f)
[1] "1" "2" "3"
> f
[1] 1    2    3    <NA>
Levels: 1 2 3
> is.na(f)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

One presumes this is a means by which one would differentiate between `NA` and `"NA"` in the way a factor is printed as it prints without the quotes, even for character labels/levels:

```
> f2 <- factor(c("NA",NA))
> f2
[1] NA   <NA>
Levels: NA
> is.na(f2)
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one exception might be data.table.
There it seems that a character field prints it as < NA >, while a numeric one as NA. NB: I added extra spaces in < NA >, otherwise this webpage did not show it properly.

```
library("data.table")

y<-data.table(a=c("a","b",NA))

print(y)
      a
1:    a
2:    b
3: < NA >

factor(y$a)

[1] a    b    < NA >

Levels: a b

## we enter a numeric argument

y<-data.table(a=c(1,2,NA))

print(y)
    a
1:  1
2:  2
3: NA

factor(y$a)

[1] 1    2    < NA >

Levels: 1 2
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this is an exception about. The above answers essentially say when `NA` is in `factor` or `character`, it is printed as `<NA>`. This is the same as what you demonstrate using `data.table`.