# R Data Frame - Convert all <NA> to blank(" ") for character columns

Tags: r

I am looking for a solution to convert all  to blank(' ') for all character columns in the data frame. I would prefer Base R solution. I tried solution described in ([Setting <NA> to blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19592706/setting-na-to-blank)
) but it requires to convert entire data frame as a factor and that creates an issue for numeric columns e.g.

```r
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,NA), y=c("a","b",NA))
```

**To convert numeric NA to 0**

```r
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
```

**To convert character  to Blank(" ") - It converts all columns to character.**

```r
df <- sapply(df, as.character)
df[is.na(df)] <- " "
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your dataframe with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,NA), y=c("a","b",NA), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Find character columns

```
cols <- sapply(df, is.character)
```

Turn them to blank

```
df[cols][is.na(df[cols])] <- ' '
df

#   x y
#1  1 a
#2  2 b
#3 NA
```

Answer (score 2):

It's maybe not the most elegant way but using `dplyr`, you can convert all factor column to character column using `mutate_if` and then replace all NA by "" in character columns by using `ifelse` in `mutate_if`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_if(is.factor, ~as.character(.)) %>%
  mutate_if(is.character, ~ifelse(is.na(.)," ",.))

   x y
1  1 a
2  2 b
3 NA
```