# How are missings represented in R?

Tags: r, na, missing-data

**Beforehand**

Most obvious answer to the title is that missings are represented with `NA` in R. Dummy data:

```
x <- c("a", "NA", "<NA>", NA)
```

We can transform all elements of `x` to characters using `x_paste0 <- paste0(x)`. After doing so, the second and fourth elements are same (`"NA"`) and to my knowledge this is why there is no way to backtransform `x_paste0` to `x`.

**addNA**

But working with `addNA` indicates that it is not just the `NA` itself that represents missings. In `x` only the last element is a missing. Let's transform the vector:

```
x_new <- addNA(x)
x_new
[1] a    NA   <NA> <NA>
Levels: <NA> a NA <NA>
```

Interestingly, the fourth element, i.e. the missing is shown with `<NA>` and not with `NA`. Further, now the fourth element looks same as the third. And we are told that there are no missings because when we try `any(is.na(x_new))` we get `FALSE`. At this point I would have thought that the information about what element is the missing (the third or the fourth) is simply lost as it was in `x_paste0`. But this is not true because we can actually backtransform `x_new`. See:

```
as.character(x_new)
[1] "a"    "NA"   "<NA>" NA
```

How does `as.character` know that the third element is `"<NA>"` and the fouth is an actual missing, i.e. `NA`?

Comment: Have a look here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16253789/what-is-the-difference-between-na-and-na>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably a uncleanness in the `base:::print.factor()` method.

```
x <- c("a", "NA", "<NA>", NA)

addNA(x)
# [1] a    NA   <NA> <NA>
# Levels: <NA> a NA <NA>
```

But:

```
levels(addNA(x))
# [1] "<NA>" "a"    "NA"   NA
```

So, there are no duplicated levels.

Comment: So there are no missings in x_new (see any(is.na(x_new))) but in the levels of x_new there are missings! Thus, we can simply drop the level which stands for the missing, i.e. `factor(x_new, levels= levels(x_new)[-which(is.na(levels(x_new)))])`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Usually you try to prevent this when you read your data, either a csv or other source. A bit of a silly demo using read.table on your vector sample data.

```
x <- c("a", "NA", "<NA>", NA)
x <- read.table(text = x, na.strings = c("NA", "<NA>", ""), stringsAsFactors = F)$V1
x
[1] "a" NA  NA  NA
```

But if you want to fix it afterwards

```
x <- c("a", "NA", "<NA>", NA)
na_strings <- c("NA", "<NA>", "")

unlist(lapply(x, function(v) { ifelse(v %in% na_strings, NA, v) }))

[1] "a" NA  NA  NA
```

**some notes on factors and addNA**

```
# to not be confused with character values pretending to be missing values but are not
x <- c("a", "b", "c", NA)

x_1 <- addNA(x)
x_1

# do not get confused on how the displayed output is
# [1] a    b    c    <NA>
# Levels: a b c <NA>
  
str(x_1)
# Factor w/ 4 levels "a","b","c",NA: 1 2 3 4

is.na(x_1) # as your actual values are 1, 2, 3, 4
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

is.na(levels(x_1))
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE

# but nothing is lost
x_2 <- as.character(x_1)

str(x_2)
# chr [1:4] "a" "b" "c" NA

is.na(x_2)
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Well you provide a sample where there is just one missing value, simple as that. The rest are strings that you interpret / define yourself as something else, in this case "missing". And often the case, we want to convert them to NA's as well. Perhaps I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Any function knows that the last value in your vector is `NA` and as the vector contains characters, it will be a `NA` with a typeof character. `typeof(NA) # [1] "logical"
typeof(c("NA", NA)[2]) # [1] "character"
typeof(c(1L, NA)[2]) # [1] "integer"
typeof(as.character(c(1L, NA))[2]) # "character"`. This probably does not answer your question either, but perhaps it helps your understanding.

Comment: Sure it does, you probably mean `any(is.na(levels(x_new)))` [1] TRUE

Comment: I think I understand your question a bit better regarding this. Let me update my answer with this part.

Comment: what is the purpose of x_new? `x <- c("a", "b", "c", NA, "e", NA)
which(is.na(x)) # [1] 4 6`

Comment: I understand that, but why starting with vector x where you directly can get your answer with which(is.na(x)), so what is the purpose of creating x_new first? But you can do so, get rid of your factors and get the index: `which(is.na(as.character(x_new)))`

Comment: That is "output", look how it is stored, factors are stored as index numbers. Look at my example: `Factor w/ 4 levels "a","b","c",NA: 1 2 4 3 4` Note there are 4 factor levels and it stores 4 (which is our NA factor level) on place 3 and 5. When we do `which(is.na(as.character(addNA(c("a", "b", NA, "c", NA)))))` you get those positions `[1] 3 5`

Comment: In my comments there is example with more NA's actually your example is confusing as it consists of only one NA with a few STRINGS having "NA"  in the name but they will never ever be treated as NA values no matter how or no matter the type of it. But I am out of the discussion, look how factors are stored. advisable to use str() to see the factors and the levels. as.character and as any other thing like output will do is match the numeric index values back to the associated level. And really for R your "NA" in your example is as much a string as my "a"

Comment: paste0(x) means you have to think twice before doing that, as there is no way back, actually as you mentioned yourself :) I skipped that part to easy I guess trying to convince you the attempts doing so will fail. Why not check if it is already a vector prior to pasting it into a vector and lose the information of a string named NA versus a true value NA. It is actually the same problem you will create by doing as.numeric(c("1", 2)) as after that you never will be able to create back the one that was a string and which one was not.